# External Content Types Error

Tags: external-content-type

I want to get data from SQL Server 2013. I created Business Data Connectivity Service. 
Then I click the External Content Types but I get error.  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly caused by insufficient permissions on the Business Data Connectivity Service.

Go to the Central Administration website and go to Manage service applications. Click on the Business Data Connectivity Service and check its permissions.

[image: Sharepoint permissions]

Comment: I added permisson for my user, but I still get the error. I added screenshot permission under my question. Is the Business Data Connectivity Service must be published  ?

Comment: @zengel maybe this article helps: http://spdoctor.net/Home/ErrorMessage/access-denied-by-business-data-connectivity